# FareNabber API on Sabre - where do the notifications go

Tags: sabre

I am interested in seeing if Sabre's FareNabber is an API that works for an application I am building.

The documentation here https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/fare_nabber does not explain where/how the notifications get posted to after a subscription made. All I see is the following:

```
FareNabber nabs the itinerary options and pushes the results to the customer for a purchase decision.
```

Is this an email to the customer? Is this an HTTP POST with a JSON payload to a server I provide so I can handle the actual email transmission? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re Endpoint you set this up during activation:
Note: This service requires activation, please contact your Sabre Account Representative for assistance.

Actually yes you get a JSON - its specified here: http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/fare_nabber/v100/FNB_LowFareNotification.json